# Multiple Criteria - vlookup

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to use an If(and... to grab a lookup if the weight (column F) meets the range on a second sheet between the min and max columns.

For example: If a SKU's weight is between a highsize and a low size on sheet 2 and the helper column matches, then I'd like to pull in the price.

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ermKIQnZRcWzm8ogDE7IK0fQSLohDsOBHuaUjjRi8io/edit?usp=sharing

The helper column is a join of the shape, color, and clarity, however, the carat weight will then decide what the standard industry price for that goes.

Multiple SKUs can have the same shape, color, and clarity so the weight would be the defining factor. I created helper columns to help with that part, however, I am having trouble getting a formula that would combine a lookup and an if weight is >highsize and <lowsize.

The main project I'm working on has many, many, skus so going through each one and copying is not a viable solution. The second part is that the second sheet's prices will update on a weekly basis so I need to be able to update it to populate on the first sheet.

Comment: Regarding the weight _`"weight (column F)"`_ that you've mentioned, do your refer to the `RapShape` on your `Test` sheet (`RapShape` is on the column F) Or is it the `Carat Weight` (Column G) on your `Test` sheet?

Answer (score 0):

try in P1 cell:

```
={"E-Price"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, 'e-Price Ranges'!A2:G, 7, 0)))}
```

[image]